# Convert timedelta[64] column to seconds from midnight

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the follwing dataframe:

```
tripStart_time  tripEnd_time    trip_duration   trip_duration_mins
1   22:30:00    23:15:00    00:45:00    45
2   11:00:00    11:30:00    00:30:00    30
3   09:00:00    09:15:00    00:15:00    15
4   13:30:00    14:25:00    00:55:00    55
5   09:00:00    10:15:00    01:15:00    15
```

For which the datatypes are as follows:

```
tripStart_time        timedelta64[ns]
tripEnd_time          timedelta64[ns]
trip_duration         timedelta64[ns]
trip_duration_mins              int64
dtype: object
```

I am trying to create a new columns which is the number of seconds which have passed since midnight for the first column 'tripStart_time '. I am basically trying to access each component of the time and multiply by the number of seconds in an hour/minute. I have tried the following:

```
df_time['seconds'] = (df_time['tripStart_time'].hour * 3600) + (df_time['tripStart_time'].minute * 60) + (df_time['tripStart_time'].second)
```

But get the following error:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

I am not sure how to achieve the desired result... thanks for the help.

Comment: `df_time['seconds'] = df_time['tripStart_time'].dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: Agree with above, and the direct reason for the Error is that you want `.dt.hour` not `.hour`.